# Choose the closest timestamps of two tables in mySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables.

**table alerts**

```
username -- alert -- timestamp
abc -- 3 -- 2017-12-09 13:10:42
def -- 3 -- 2017-12-12 18:10:00
xyz -- 3 -- 2017-12-11 11:00:00
```

**table pages**

```
username -- url -- timestamp
abc -- home -- 2017-12-09 13:18:42
abc -- home -- 2017-12-13 19:03:10
def -- home -- 2017-12-13 13:33:00
```

What I want to do is to show the `usernames` that are found both into the `alerts` AND on `pages`. However, I need to display only the row on `pages` that its timestamp is closest to the `alerts` timestamp.

That means

```
abc -- 3 -- 2017-12-09 13:10:42 -- home -- 2017-12-09 13:18:42
def -- 3 -- 2017-12-12 18:10:00 -- home -- 2017-12-13 13:33:00
```

**What I did so far**

```
SELECT alerts.username, alerts.alert, alerts.timestamp, pages.url, pages.timestamp
FROM   alerts 
join pages on pages.username = alerts.username
WHERE  username IN(SELECT DISTINCT username
                               FROM   pages
                               WHERE  url = 'home' 
                                      AND timestamp > 
                                          alerts.timestamp) 
GROUP  BY username
```

But this query does not return the closest, but one in random (the most recent I guess).

How can I fix this?

Comment: Your query does not produce the type of output you are looking for.

Comment: @PM77-1 true, I forgot the join. now is ok. thank you for noticing

Comment: @PM77-1 fixed again

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.username, abs(a.timestamp-p.timestamp) as difference  
FROM alerts a 
JOIN pages p ON p.username = a.username
HAVING difference = min(difference)
```

The query above will select username with the absolute difference between stamps then it will return only the row with minimum difference.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/52bc00/13)

Comment: I understand the logic, but running this on my actual data it doesnt return the correct result. For example, a visitor has multiple rows in `pages` with the home url. Without the `having` it returns 69 difference. If I put it, then the row is not shown at all. Instead, it should show the closest date to the `alerts` timestamp (which it was the same date).

Comment: could you create a fiddle with sample of your actual data and desired result?

Comment: Can you please take a look at this image https://i.imgur.com/3RI5QMQ.png

Comment: Also, I am trying it with `abs(datediff( , )`

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try with a window function:

```
select * from (
select 
  p.username,
  p.timestamp pages_timestamp,
  p.url,
  a.timestamp alerts_timestamp,
  a.alert,
  row_number() over (partition by p.username order by abs(p.timestamp - a.timestamp)) rn
from alerts a
join pages p on a.username = p.username) t
where t.rn = 1
```

We're joining the tables on username to compute the time difference for each matching pair. We assign a `row_number` to each row within the partition that shares the same username (ordered by time difference), and only select the rows with row number 1 (i.e. those with the smallest time difference)

In case you have plenty of rows per user in each table, you might want to add  a `where abs(p.timestamp - a.timestamp) < SOME_LIMIT` to the select table.

**Update**: In case you're running MySQL 5.6 or similar, you're out of luck with window functions and you would have to apply the old group-by-then-join trick:

```
select 
  p.username,
  p.url,
  p.timestamp pages_timestamp,
  a.alert,
  a.timestamp alerts_timestamp
from (
  select 
    p.username,
    min(abs(p.timestamp - a.timestamp)) min_diff
  from alerts a
  join pages p on a.username = p.username
  group by p.username) t
join pages p on p.username = t.username
join alerts a on a.username = p.username
where abs(p.timestamp - a.timestamp) = t.min_diff
```

Note that this will yield duplicate rows per user if (and only if) there are multiple rows in `pages` that have an identical time difference to some row in alerts for the same `username`.

[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xhwdjKHYZc8dhFjTLaFeye/0) (using MySQL 5.6)
[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/btQgCJE1wNYiJJ2er7hbGR/0) (using MySQL 8)

Comment: thank you, however i am not using mysql 8. does this work on other versions too?

Comment: I updated my answer with a MySQL 5.6 compatible solution

Answer (score 0):

Here's another thought - create a temp table with the minimum time difference between the two time stamps (per user) - then link to the temp table and with a WHERE clause get the closest time stamp by matching the value of the calculation.

Code example:

```
    SELECT A.UserName, MIN(CONVERT(DECIMAL(6,2),P.TimeStamp -A.timestamp)) TimeDif
    INTO #Temp1
    FROM Alerts A INNER JOIN Pages P ON A.UserName = P.username
    GROUP BY A.UserName

    SELECT A.UserName, A.Alert, P.url, P.timestamp
    FROM Alerts A INNER JOIN
       Pages P ON A.UserName = P.username INNER JOIN
       #Temp1 T ON A.UserName = T.UserName
    WHERE T.TimeDif = CONVERT(DECIMAL(6,2),P.TimeStamp -A.timestamp)
```

Comment: Probably, it also doesn't account for multiple records in 'Alerts' with exactly the same timestamp.   I've done something similar in a table with millions of rows and the execution time wasn't bad.